# How to get facebook profile picture with 'F'-logo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Graph API and I need to get users' profiles pictures by their UIDs.
It's easy to do: http://graph.facebook.com/[Facebook UID]/picture

I remember, some time ago, there was a litte Facebook Logo (litter 'f'-char) on these profile pictures. But now, I get only profile pictures without this logo.

How can I get images with this 'f'-logo?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook doesn't store images with the 'f' on, so it's a little hacky to get at them.

I've found that this works:

You'll need the final image url, after graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture redirects.

[http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?&url=[imageurl]&logo](http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?&url=%5Bimageurl%5D&logo)

eg. [me](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318000441/https://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible using the graph api.

It was possible using FQL (dont know if it is still working):

```
SELECT pic_with_logo FROM user WHERE uid = "..."
```

or use xfbml with `<fb:profile-pic facebook-logo="true">`

Comment: facebook calls this profile-pic with favicon.. try google. Maybe u can find something better then me.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery and JS API you can make an FQL call:

```
FB.api({ method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT uid, pic_with_logo FROM user WHERE uid = me()' }, function(response) {
    var user    = response[0];
    $('#container').append('<img src="'+user.pic_with_logo+'"/><br>');
});
```

also you can try:
`pic_small_with_logo`, `pic_big_with_logo`, `pic_square_with_logo` and the `pic_with_logo` i use in example.

here is the user table:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tom's answer, Here is php example to get user's

```
$_json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/[FACEBOOK_UID]?fields=picture'));
if (isset($_json->picture)) {
  header("Location: http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?&url=" . $_json->picture . "&logo");
  exit;
}
```

Here is what we do:

- Query picture url via opengraph
- Get the picture url from json object
- redirect the page to facebook image handler with addition &logo to url