# How to display FB icon on a Facebook avatar?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

How to display the FB logo on the image? like this:
[avatar](http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBxxmDnWcPft_dH&url=http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/49869_1022247481_8924_q.jpg&logo&v=5&t=1337139335&ttl=3888000&sig=HPquGIV3J7zPpNVbSpdelA--~B)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming (i.e, for the Facebook Platform).

Comment: Nevermind. I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10031571/381720

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get facebook profile picture with 'F'-logo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459564/how-to-get-facebook-profile-picture-with-f-logo)

Answer (score 0):

I think the picture may be edited solely by the person using photo editor like photoshop or some kind.
My friend also gave some logo on his profile picture on FB.

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay an image over it if you use css to do this very easily if you are just looking to do this on your website, otherwise, use photoshop to create an image with it included.